# Most efficient way to translate a Sitecore website to 4 other languages (Not having the translators in you Sitecore CMS)

Tags: localization, sitecore

I am looking for a good way to translate an excisting Sitecore installation (English language is available) to 4 other languages (Russian , Chinese, Portuguese etc.) A dedicated translation company will translate all texts we deliver to the specified languages, but I'm curious on how other companies set this up. I thought about just exporting all Sitecore items which have to be translated using the Database language Export function in Sitecore and having the translation company edit those files. By just replacing the language tags in the XML we should be able to import this file as the newly created other language, however I'm affraid that this XML structure will be totally useless for a translation company and that they will drown in the codes inside this XML. How can we efficiently do this? Is there any other way then just giving those translation people access to the Sitecore environment and having them edit the languages here? Any Shared Source Module to achieve this? I still have alot of questions, is there anyone with some experience in achieving this?

Comment: How much content are you planning to translate?

Comment: A complete Sitecore website with let's say around 300 / 400 page items and different Dictionary settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your primary options are either the language export/import functionality (as you mention), or a workflow-based solution that integrates with your translation agency's Translation Management System (if they have one -- hopefully they do).

The former is better for the initial translation. Typically, your agency should be able to handle translation of content within XML files. A good one can. If you create all needed language versions beforehand and copy english content into them, it will make the files easier to work with as they'll have tags for the new languages in them already. I've seen the creation of these layers done with Revolver (http://www.codeflood.net/revolver/) but could also be done with custom code or workflow.

For ongoing maintenance of your translated content, you'll probably want to integrate through workflow. Clay Tablet Technologies (http://www.clay-tablet.com/) have a middleware component w/ Sitecore integration that can make this easier, depending on your translation agency. You can also do your own workflow-based integration, with workflow commands that allow your users to send content for translation. Then you'd need some sort of listener that pulls the translated content back in, and continues the workflow.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Agree with @techphoria414 - either find some way they can read the exported language files or build in the translation step and access as part of your workflow design. I'm assuming you will need to maintain these pages over time so sorting this process out now is probably for the best.

Answer (score 1):

You could also check out Lionbrdige (http://en-us.lionbridge.com/sitecore-and-lionbridge-announce-partnership-to-help-companies-thrive-across-borders.htm) as a solution.

From my own experience our customers normally use the Sitecore import/export function as a first step and then use Lionbridge or Clay Tablet as a service.

One important thing to think about with translations is the ongoing work. The initial translation is rather simple, but the second and so on might be more troublesome. What if different changes has been made in different languages. If local changes were made in the content for sat the french version you couldn´t just send the English version (second translate then) since you would also have to accomodate for the regional changes in the content.

Answer (score 1):

Having worked with literally dozens of Sitecore clients worldwide — and helped get content to and from all the largest, and many smaller translation firms —, I can attest to the ineffeciency of trying to do translation in situ, that is in Sitecore. I liken it to asking an electrician to come over and rewire your house, but as they reach for their toolbox from the truck you tell them, "Nope — you need to do it by hand".

The very best way to manage anything more than a page or two of content for translation is to export it seamlessly. Deliver it to the LSP in a proper format (XML or XLIFF) and, when possible, auto import it to their TMS. Once translated, the content should then flow seamlessly back into Sitecore.

You can code this yourself — but the pitfalls are non-trivial just on the Sitecore side. (If you want intuitive UI's, scalability, and all the features that meet the needs of translation). Let alone the challenges of connecting to the systems LSP's use. (For example, who here knows the relative merits/risks of using SLD's Nexus connector versus their CTA for connecting to TMS?)

As kindly mentioned above, there are commecially available solutions that meet all these needs and more. So if you've got even a modest amount of content — and want to send that to any translation provider of your choice — I'd be happy to discuss how we can help.

Answer (score -1):

The main issue with translation isn't technical at all, the XML export is a simple enough format and all agencies should be able to deal with it with no porblems. as others have suggested, maintenance after the initial translation is slightly more problematic but they also point to tools to achieve this.

The main issue we've found with translation is actually linguistic: how to achieve consistency of phrasing and  that matches the original but is sufficiently adjusted to local requirements. Translation companies usually have software to aid this - libraries of of the phrases they translate etc. -  working with an exported XML file doesn't provide the context of seeing content in situ. A particular item may be translated correctly and the site consistently, but as each page may be built from multiple items there can easily be conflicts between content as presented.

That makes working with the Sitecore backend (maybe with field security settings to limit ) or in the page editor (possibly pre filling fields with English values) a viable idea.

Comment: Having worked at a language service provider both as a project manager and software developer I can tell you that every single translator worth his/her salt will cringe at the thought of working in a web-based system. It's the equivalent of having to code in Notepad if you're used to e.g. Visual Studio. It takes more time, introduces more errors and will end up costing the client more.

Comment: That's possibly a bit of a harsh markdown. The point was that when working with Sitecore the material for translation is largely stripped of context when exported. I'm certainly not claiming that using the Sitecore interface is always the best option, only that there may be Sitecore specific drawbacks to other options that are worth taking into account.

Comment: If the goal is to produce consistent translations then working in an environment where the translator can't use the tools they are used to (including translation memories, well-refined QA tools etc) is in direct conflict to that. Yes, context matters a lot, and basically any software localization can potentially suffer from this. But I guarantee you that there are better ways to handle this (e.g. client reviews and feedback) than forcing translations to be done in-place in a CMS.

Comment: I don't think I've ever mentionined forcing translation to be done in the CMS, just mentioned that it's a "viable idea", especially once the bulk of the translation has been done externally and imported into the system. How viable it is will depend on the amount of translation that needs to be done, the complexity of the site, frequency of update, who your translators are (professional external translators, or internal webmasters with detailed business knowledge of what they're translating and how it needs to be localised for their own market) and what tools they are used to using.